# How to stop the rotation with cancelAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, requestanimationframe

I am working currently with threejs and the `requestAnimationFrame` method. I try to rotate a camera to the right by holding a button. My problem here is, that by releasing the button, the rotation doesn't stop end gets accelerated everytime I press the button again.

***HTML:***

```
<button id="right" onmousedown="rotateRight()" onmouseup="rotatestopRight()">Right</button>
```

***JavaScript:***

```
function rotateRight(){
    mainPivot.add(camera);
    mainPivot.rotation.y+=Math.PI/180;
    requestAnimationFrame( rotateRight );
}

function rotatestopRight(){
    cancelAnimationFrame( rotateRight );
}
```

I tried to solve this by making `mainPivot.rotation.y-=Math.PI/180;`on release, which worked, but it's not the best solution, since `onmouseup` event can easily be bypassed. Any idea how to get around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using it incorrectly. `requestAnimationFrame` returns an id which you use when you call `cancelAnimationFrame`.

```
var id = requestAnimationFrame();

...

cancelAnimationFrame( id );
```